# JQuery .addClass() does his job, but the browser does not repaint

Tags: jquery, css, browser, addclass, repaint

I know this is not new but I already tried every remedy I found without solving the problem...

I have some JQuery code that give *background-color* to a div and *color* to h* by assigning dynamically a class.

1. The css is loaded correctly and applied to everything
2. The .addClass method is doing exactly what I expect, using Chrome's DevTools I can see the class is assigned to the right elements
3. The colors don't change
4. In the style inspector, nothing appears about the new style applied
5. If i try something like this

   ```
   $.fn.redraw = function(){
        return $(this).each(
            function(){ 
                var redraw = this.offsetHeight; 
            }
        );
   };
   ```

   calling it at the end of changes this way

   ```
   $(selector).redraw();
   ```

   does not work.
6. FF/Chrome behave the same.

If I change the code, using .attr("style",value) insted of .addClass to assign inline style it works!
But I dont like that solution, I'd prefer to avoid hardcode inline styles using external CSS.

Does someone have a suggestion? It's two days i'm trying to guess the right step...

Comment: can you post a link/jsfiddle? which out seeing the code you are talking about its hard to suggest options (i.e. you've mentioned code to add a class and you css styles that relate to that class, but none are here, just some code you shouldnt need)

Comment: check the css files, are these loaded correctly?

Comment: try !important keyword in the css class for background property.

Comment: @saqibahmad I hope you meant use !important for testing that it works to see if something else is overriding it? and not as a solution. ;-)

Comment: Just a guess: You might have a syntax error in your CSS above where the styles for this class are defined. The CSS parser might give up on that error, but still apply styles defined above it.

Comment: There is so much code it would be hard to copy everything possibly involved here. Asap i'll try to arrange some cut the most significative parts.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same problem, I believe I solved doing this:

```
 $(this).removeClass("old_class");
 $(this).css({ 'background-color' : '' });
 $(this).addClass("new_class");
```

First remove the old class, then set background-color to nothing and finally add the new class.

Comment: Nope, no effect.
May be related to the fact that the content affected from CSS is loaded at runtime?

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsyq9qa8/) and make the changes that you consider useful to understand your case. http://jsfiddle.net/rsyq9qa8/

Comment: thanks, in facts it is what I do but the colors remain the same. If i add the color inline, it's ok, if I add the class that whay nothing happens in the frontend while the class is added in the back...